# How to create JWT with security algorithms "none"

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I would like to test if my application is susceptible to a JWT with algorithm "none" attack. So as a test, I need to create a token with algorithm "none". I am trying the following code, but it is not working. I am getting the following error: "Unable to create the SignatureProvider."

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens;

string jwt = GenerateJwt("janes@somewhere.net", "IssuerApp", "RecievingApp", "Password", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
Console.WriteLine(jwt);


static string GenerateJwt(string subject, string issuer, string audience, string secretKey, TimeSpan duration)
{
    DateTime nowUtcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime expiresUtcDate = nowUtcDate.Add(duration);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
    SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(bytes), SecurityAlgorithms.None);

    SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, subject) }),
        Issuer = issuer,
        Audience = audience,
        Expires = expiresUtcDate,
        IssuedAt = nowUtcDate,
        NotBefore = nowUtcDate,
        SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
    };

    JsonWebTokenHandler jsonWebTokenHandler = new();

    return jsonWebTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
}
```

**Edit 1**
I think I have to do the following:

```
SigningCredentials signingCredentials = null!;
```

The token looks like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJub25lIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJzdWIiOiJqYW5lc0Bzb21ld2hlcmUubmV0IiwiYXVkIjoiUmVjaWV2aW5nQXBwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjg0Mzc4NTI5LCJpc3MiOiJJc3N1ZXJBcHAiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODQzNzgyMjksIm5iZiI6MTY4NDM3ODIyOX0.
```

The header looks like this:

```
{
  "alg": "none",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Comment: Is `SecurityAlgorithms.None` symmetric or asymmetric, I wonder.

Comment: @possum I think you pointed me in the right direction. I've updated the question.